# JavaScript is not working in FF browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
/* Only numbers input in the CELL text box */
function ValidateKeyNumber() 
{   
    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    var allowed='0123456789';

    return allowed.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) !=-1 ;
}
```

This JS working fine in IE & Chrome but not in FF.  Can you please tell me what is wrong with this? I need the JS to work in these 3 major browsers.

FYI:

1. I use the latest FF version.
2. JavaScript is enabled in FF.
3. I don't use jQuery

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

***FULL PAGE CODE:***

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>JavaSCript Input Test</title>
<script>
/* Only numbers in mobile text-box */
function ValidateKeyNumber() 
{   
    var key=window.event.keyCode;
    var allowed='0123456789';

    return allowed.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) !=-1 ;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form>
<label>Cell Number:</label><input type="text" name="cell" size="30" maxlength="10" onKeyPress="return ValidateKeyNumber()"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue? Try here http://jsbin.com

Comment: @elclanrs Please see the post again, I've added the full code to it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `window.event` isn't defined in Firefox. The solution is to use the argument passed to the event handler, for example

```
<label>Cell Number:</label><input type="text" name="cell" size="30" maxlength="10" onKeyPress="return ValidateKeyNumber(event)"/>

function ValidateKeyNumber(event) {   
    var key=(event||window.event).keyCode;
    var allowed='0123456789';

    return allowed.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(key)) !=-1 ;
}
```

Comment: i think better to use (event || window.event).keyCode -- to keep IE compatibility

Comment: @VasilVanchuk I'm looking for what version of IE did miss the event argument, I think it's so old we shouldn't care.

Comment: maybe you are right. Documentation (inc msdn ) recommend use this construction but i did not met this error from IE8

Comment: @dystroy , can you please help me and present this in the full code added to the question?

Comment: @SULTAN I answered. What's missing ?

Comment: @dystroy , yes you did, I wrote my comment while you updating your post, thanks.. it worked fine and accepted

Comment: @VasilVanchuk Couldn't find the information, [so I asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552338/what-version-of-ie-doesnt-pass-the-event-as-argument-to-listeners).